# How to add timestamping signature to System.IO.Packaging.Package?

Tags: .net, certificate, signing, trusted-timestamp

There is a way to create packages, add some parts and sign it with a `X509Certificate`.

I would also like to add a timestamping signature to the package.

If the certificate **expires** or gets **revoked** the signature should remain valid if the package parts have been timestamped *before* the expiration/revokation.

P.S. I'm using the `System.IO.Packaging.Package` class defined in the `WindowsBase.dll` assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works it you're both the **creator** and the **consumer** of the package:

1. Use a secure Internet server to get the *trusted* timestamp.
2. Redefine the certificate chain policy to include the timestamp validation in the certificate chain.

Comment: I have a trusted timestamp, but am trying to understand how to include  that when signing. However, I would not be the consumer of the package...

Can you elaborate on the 2nd step?

Answer (score 0):

Digital signatures in System.IO.Packaging rely on [XMLDSIG](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/). Tusted Timestamping (or secure timestamping) in terms of [RFC 3161](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt) was added on top with XML Advanced Electronic Signatures ([XAdES](https://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/)) and the XAdES-T Profile.
Microsoft Office documents use System.IO.Packaging as their format and so the Microsoft Documentation ([MS-OFFCRYPTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-offcrypto/341ca65a-95b8-439b-a5a0-d6868b828854)) mentions XAdES-T as the form used.

Unfortunately there is no built in support in the .NET Framework itself. While Microsoft Office has the ability to utilize trusted time stamps for digital signatures.

[Microsoft France](https://web.archive.org/web/20121020114751/http://www.microsoft.com/france/interop/ressources/xades.aspx) published a library to support the standards in 2012 but it went offline and is not maintained anymore. But there is a snapshot of the sources on [Github](https://github.com/Caliper/Xades).

There are also a few other libraries your might consider helpful

- [FirmaXadesNet45](https://github.com/ctt-gob-es/FirmaXadesNet45/blob/master/FirmaXadesNet/Upgraders/XadesTUpgrader.cs)
- [Xades-T-Validator](https://github.com/Temppus/Xades-T-Validator)
- [XAdES-Signer](https://github.com/silegis-mg/XAdES-Signer)